# Codeigniter access function in different controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am pretty new to codeigniter. I am facing an inconvenient issue. I have code like this in profile.php (controller):

```
 public function edit()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();

        if($post)
        {
            //checking session username (if logged in)
            if(isset($this->session->userdata('username') && !empty($this->session->userdata('username')))
            {

            }else{
             /***************************REFERENCE DIFFERENT CONTROLLER HERE*********/
                $this->load->view('login');    //should I write membership/index?
            }

        }else{

        }

    }
```

So I check if user logged in, if yes, code executes. if not, I wish to redirect to a function in different controller i.e. membership.php and it is the index() function of that controller. How can I reference that?

Comment: use helper function redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use redirect variable

```
     public function edit()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();

    if($post)
    {
        //checking session username (if logged in)
        if(isset($this->session->userdata('username') && !empty($this->session->userdata('username')))
        {
             redirect('membership');
        }else{
         /***************************REFERENCE DIFFERENT CONTROLLER HERE*********/
            $this->load->view('login');    //should I write membership/index?
              redirect('membership'); // you can use this where u want to refrence/redirect
        }

    }else{

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Another solution is to create a class and extend it. That is much cleaner than redirect. Just for future reference

Answer (score 1):

use redirect("membership/index"); for redirection in codeigniter